# Why $p \to q$ is true when $p$ is false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I know the concept of vacuously true statement. So when $p$ is false, it yield $p \to q$ as true, no matter what $q$ is. What I have been told is "because there is no specific condition placed on $q$, so it is vacuously true".

Even I though this statement is not clear to me "*there is no specific condition placed on $q$*". But let's keep it aside and let me know, why only `true`, why not `false`?

Since there can't be any other value than `true` or `false` in the logic (boolean based). Why $p \to q$ is `true` when $p$ is false, why not `false`?

Comment: Presumably, you defined → in terms of truth tables, so it is true by definition. As for why not have it be false if p is false, imagine if we defined it that way. Then p → q is equivalent to p ∧ q, and so would be a redundant symbol, we would just use the conjunction instead.

Comment: @MichaelCarey I see. That also makes sense.